# How to pass list of values into a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a Student bean which is iterated to display the mark reports of students in a table.Each row in a table is provided with a radio button selection followed by viewing the report on onclick event.

I am passing the value of the student id by setting it in the radio button and subject in a hidden input field

```
<input type="radio" name="studentList.id" value="TE3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="studentList.subject" value="Mathematics"/>
```

These two parameters are needed for retrieving the report based on subject and student id.

But I can't pass these parameters as they should be .

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions or ways to attain the requisite ?

Thanks for your time .

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/jaggs/f8su70mc/

Comment: what is studentList here?

Comment: studentList is a class with getter setter methods.

Comment: have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you check radio   button ckecked or  not
    if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
         // do something
     }

use is parameter in radio button field

for getting values:--
    $('input[name="studentList.subject"]').val();

i hope it help you

Comment: Thanks for your time.Your answer seems optimistic ..Let me try it out and reply back

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of...

```
$('input[name="studentList.subject"]').val();
```

This would return the any input the value, where its attr of name = "studentList.subject".

Sorry if its not what is required... :S